# Login can get any data from database but show result "Unregister Account"

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, ionic-framework

After register into form , data does exist in the database but when i login the data can't be fetch instead it gives a msg " Unregister Account"

Doesn't display any error but just display the msg.

```php
if ($postjson['action'] == 'login') { //login
    $password = md5($postjson['password']);
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$postjson[username]' AND password='$password'");
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($check > 0) {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $datauser = array(
            'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => $data['password']
        );

        if ($data['status'] == 'y') {
            $result = json_encode(array('success' => true, 'result' => $datauser));
        } else {
            $result = json_encode(array('success' => false, 'msg' => 'Account Inactive'));
        }

    } else {
        $result = json_encode(array('success' => true, 'msg' => 'Unregister Account'));
    }

    echo $result;
}
```

The database

[image: The database]

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5 for password hashing! [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even states: _"Warning - It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your database?

Comment: What's the size of your "password"-column?

Comment: you have a condition/validation in your configuration to database? can you check if your database is connected successfully?

Comment: the size of password is 18

Comment: `md5()` returns a string that's 32 characters so if the database column is 18, the hashes are truncated and won't work anymore. But as mentioned, you shouldn't use `md5()` in the first place. Use `password_hash()`. Just remember that the hashes from that function are even longer. You then need to set the database column to _at least_ 60 characters.

Comment: So the problem may come from the hashes?

Comment: If the field is 18 chars, then the hashes are definitely truncated and invalid.

Comment: use field type TEXT to store your hash as in existing structure, your hashed passwords are not fully stored in the database and the comparison fails due to that

Comment: @RajeshKakkad Thank youuu! Its fixed!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the knowledge. I appreciate your help :D

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is not getting any records because of password not matching in database.
Once your query get record it will work, Just debug why password is not matching, because of md5? give it try